# Woocommerce add custom price with category check

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to add **custom price** to **woocommerce** cart I am using **woocommerce_before_calculate_totals**  hook and its working perfectly now I want to add this **custom price** to cart only if products are in specific category. Any Help Please

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
    function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
         $custom_price = 50; // This will be your custome price  
         foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
         }

     }

    }
```

Please can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {   
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {   
        $productId = $value['data']->id;
        if ( has_term( 'category-to-becheck', 'product_cat', $productId ) ) {
        {
            $c_price = $value['data']->price; 
            $your_custom_price = //
            $value['data']->price = $value['data']->price + $your_custom_price;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot vote up because I have reputation less than but your answer is accepted thanks bro.